# Cannot unpack values and append to lists?

Tags: python

This for loop should be generating two lists of question and answers respectively, but the output is only the last value of the last element in the original list. I'm wondering why this is happening. Well aware there's another way to do it, but why isn't this particular method  of unpacking and appending isn't working? Thanks

```
   question_list = ['1+1=2', '2+2=4', '7-4=3']
   questions = []
   answers = []
   for question in question_list:
       q, a = question.split("=")
       questions.append(q)
       answers.append(a)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Can you add an example of what the current output is?

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Results ```['1+1', '2+2', '7-4']``` for questions and ```['2', '4', '3']``` for answers. Make sure you are printing it right

Comment: You're probably looking at `question` instead of `questions`?

Comment: *but the output is only ...* - your program generates no output. It would be helpful to understand your problem if you actually show how you get the output...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine once I fixed the bad formatting in the questions:

```
>>> question_list = ['1+1=2', '2+2=4', '7-4=3']
>>> questions = []
>>> answers = []
>>> for question in question_list:
...     q, a = question.split("=")
...     questions.append(q)
...     answers.append(a)
...
>>> questions, answers
(['1+1', '2+2', '7-4'], ['2', '4', '3'])
```

FWIW, a more concise way of doing this is with `zip`:

```
>>> questions, answers = zip(*[q.split("=") for q in question_list])
>>> questions, answers
(('1+1', '2+2', '7-4'), ('2', '4', '3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

the program is running fine. 
output: ['1+1', '2+2', '7-4'] ['2', '4', '3']
this was the output when i simply did

```
print(questions, answers)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working right, you might be printing `question` instead of `questions`.

Another format to generate 2 list using list comprehension:

```
questions = [x.split("=")[0] for x in question_list]
answers = [x.split("=")[1] for x in question_list]
print(questions, answers)
```